# How can I write this Query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables Y and X. each item of Y can have many Xi like this:

```
Y   X
--  --
A   X1  √
B   X1
B   X2
B   X3
C   X2
D   X1
D   X2
E   X1  √
```

I want to get Ys that only have X1 that is show by **tick**.
What is the query?

I should mention that my Database is Android Sqlite.

```
Select * 
From Y 
Inner join X 
on Y.id = X.Yid 
where X.id is only X1 and nothing else
```

How can I write a real query equivalent by `is only X1 and nothing else`

Comment: so this query which you wrote gives wrong results?

Comment: @Drax `is only x1` is a Pseudocode (Pseudoquery). How can I write a real equivalent query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you want all `Y` which do have an `X1`, but which do not have any other `X`. In SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Y
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT X.id
              FROM X
              WHERE X.id = Y.Xid
                AND X.name = 'X1')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT X.id
                  FROM X
                  WHERE X.id = Y.Xid
                    AND X.name != 'X1')
```

Alternatively, the first subquery could be written as a join:

```
SELECT Y.*
FROM Y JOIN X
       ON Y.Xid = X.id
WHERE X.name = 'X1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT X2.id
                  FROM X AS X2
                  WHERE X2.id = Y.Xid
                    AND X2.name != 'X1')
```

Answer (score 0):

the query could be:

```
 Select * 
  From Y 
  inner join X 
 on Y.Xid = X.id 
  where X.id = 'X1'
```

Comment: **Wrong!** This also returns `B   X1`. `B` has another record `B   X2` and `B   X3`

Comment: well @breceivemail then you need to show those columns that make the starred ones different. What are them? How do you know that they are starred? BEcasue if you want only that, from the info I have I could add where X.id = 'X1' and Y.Y in ('A', 'E')

Comment: These records are obvious. They only has X1 and **nothing else**

Comment: so the question is. Why they have a *? Because they are the first and the last one or why?

Comment: I separated them by a Start. Start is not data. It is something like tick.

Comment: I know that star is only a tick. Why you put a star on those specific records?

Comment: I replaced the stars by ticks

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
            Y +
            " where X=x1", null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String yarray[] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Y"));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

Now yarray[] will contain all your y values
```